# CMake finds Intel C++, Fortran, but not C, ar, ld

Tags: cmake

I am trying to make my CMake project work **only** with Intel compilers. I've started [from this thread](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/Intel-compilers-td7548790.html), and I have now this `CMakeLists.txt` file that *half* works:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(oo Fortran)

enable_language(Fortran)
enable_language(C)

find_program(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER NAMES ifort)
find_program(CMAKE_C_COMPILER NAMES icc)
find_program(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER NAMES icpc)
find_program(CMAKE_AR NAMES xiar)
find_program(CMAKE_LINKER NAMES xild)

if (CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER MATCHES CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER-NOTFOUND OR
    CMAKE_C_COMPILER MATCHES CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND OR
    CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER MATCHES CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND OR
    CMAKE_AR MATCHES CMAKE_AR-NOTFOUND OR
    CMAKE_LINKER MATCHES CMAKE_LINKER-NOTFOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find Intel compiler.  You may need to run `. /opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64'")
endif ()

message(">>>>> ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")
message(">>>>> ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
message(">>>>> ${CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER}")
message(">>>>> ${CMAKE_AR}")
message(">>>>> ${CMAKE_LINKER}")

set(dialect "-w -qopenmp -stand f18 -free -u -qopenmp-simd -qopt-report=5 -mavx -arch AVX")
set(bounds "-w -qopenmp -check bounds")
set(symbols "-debug full")

set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG} ${dialect} ${bounds} ${symbols}")
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} ${dialect}")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c99")

add_executable(oo animal_module.f90 cat_module.f90 main.f90)
set_property(TARGET oo PROPERTY LINKER_LANGUAGE Fortran)
```

The problem is that it correctly finds Intel's C++ compiler, Fortran compiler, but **not the other** options I've asked for (C, linker, assembler), and they are set to Apple's, as you can see from the output:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /Users/sensei/Documents/Projects/oo
-- The Fortran compiler identification is Intel 19.0.4.20190416
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/local/bin/ifort
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/local/bin/ifort  -- works
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
-- Checking whether /usr/local/bin/ifort supports Fortran 90
-- Checking whether /usr/local/bin/ifort supports Fortran 90 -- yes
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.0.11000033
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
>>>>> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
>>>>> /usr/local/bin/icpc
>>>>> /usr/local/bin/ifort
>>>>> /usr/bin/ar
>>>>> /usr/bin/ld
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/sensei/Documents/Projects/oo/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

Of course this is from both command line and CLion, I've also read about `CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER` and similar, but [they are deprecated](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeForceCompiler.html).

Any clue on why this is happening?

Comment: Probably, variables `CMAKE_AR` and `CMAKE_LINKER` are **already set** when you try to find them with `find_program`. Most likely, `enable_languate()` sets them. Such variables could be set **before** the `project()` call. But the better place for them is a *toolchain file*.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I moved the `find_program` section before enabling languages, now C, C++, and Fortran compilers are ok, but `ld` and `ar` still point to the standard ones in `/usr/bin`. Weird.

Comment: `project()` call enables languages too.

Comment: @Tsyvarev you're perfectly right, finding them before `project` works. If you'd turn your comment into an answer I'd mark it as solved.